# How can I dynamically prevent a drop on a particular FrameworkElement sometimes?

Tags: wpf

I'm authoring a drag and drop in WPF. I'd like to prevent a drop on a framework element in certain circumstances. Is there a way I can use a handler (like OnMouseMove) to determine if the drop should be permitted, and block it if the drop shouldn't be allowed?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`DragOver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dragdrop.dragover) event:

> This event is raised continuously while a dragged object is within the bounds of an element that is acting as a drop target.
>
> ...
>
> In the `DragOver` event handler, you typically check that the transferred data is in a format that the drop target can process. You can also check whether any modifier keys are pressed, which typically indicates whether the user intends a move or a copy action. After these checks are performed, you set the [`DragEventArgs.Effects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.drageventargs.effects) property to notify the drag source what effect dropping the data will have.

To disallow the drop, you would set `DragEventArgs.Effects` to `DragDropEffects.None`.